# How do I work with Ansible list of dicts?

Tags: ansible

I'm so confused with this.  If I have a file containing:

```
users:
- name: jconnor
  first: john
  last: connor
  uid: 3003
- name: sconnor
  first: sarah
  last: connor
  uid: 3001
```

How do I get the details of each user? With this simple playbook:

```
- name: create users
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: Include vars
    include_vars:
      file: user_list.yml
      name: users
  - name: debug
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    with_dict: "{{ users }}"
```

I get the following which I can't use:

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={'value': [{u'last': u'connor', u'uid': 3003, u'name': u'jconnor', u'first': u'john'}, {u'last': u'connor', u'uid': 3001, u'name': u'sconnor', u'first': u'sarah'}], 'key': u'users'}) => {
    "msg": {
        "key": "users",
        "value": [
            {
                "first": "john",
                "last": "connor",
                "name": "jconnor",
                "uid": 3003
            },
            {
                "first": "sarah",
                "last": "connor",
                "name": "sconnor",
                "uid": 3001
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to create user accounts with this but I simply don't understand how to use this structure.

Note that this is part of a larger structure and I can't change it.

Thanks

Comment: Simply remove `name: users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `users` variable is a list of dicts, you should loop with `loop` or `with_items`. Then we can access the key of each dict with `item.key`. E.g.: `item.name`, `item.uid`, etc.

Note that you are importing the variables from the file with the name `users`. So this variable now contains the `users` hash of that file. If you skip `name: users` in `include_var`, then you can directly access the `users` dict while looping.

```yaml
  tasks:
  - include_vars:
      file: user_list.yml
      name: users
  - debug:
        msg: "Username is {{ item.name }}, full name is {{ item.first }} {{ item.last }}, userid is {{ item.uid }}"
    with_items: "{{ users.users }}"
```

This outputs message (showing 1 item):

```
ok: [localhost] => (item={u'last': u'connor', u'uid': 3003, u'name': u'jconnor', u'first': u'john'}) => {
    "msg": "Username is jconnor, full name is john connor, userid is 3003"
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the quick response.  When I run your loop, ansible errors out and complains about undefined variables.

Comment: I have pasted working code and actual console output. Which variable is undefined?

Comment: The error is: fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to be in /path/to/ansible/ex447/create_users.yml': line 12, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - debug:\n      ^ here\n"}

Comment: As you are including vars from the file with the name `users`, there is a sub-dict called `users` within that. So we have to loop with `users.users`. I will update the answer.